# Simple nested setTimeout() only runs once (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, nested, settimeout

For some reason my galleryScroll() function only runs once, even though the function calls itself using setTimeout(). I'm thinking the issue may be related to scope, but I'm not sure:

http://jsfiddle.net/CYEBC/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('#box').offset().left;
    var y = $('#box').offset().top;
    galleryScroll();

    function galleryScroll() {
        x = x + 1;
        y = y + 1;
        $('#box').offset({
            left: x,
            top: y
        });
        setTimeout('galleryScroll()', 100);
    }
});​
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: No question in the code either

Comment: I figured the JSFiddle link was sufficient, but I added code. Please remove your downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you're calling the galleryScroll() function in your setTimeout. Change that line to this:

```
   setTimeout(galleryScroll, 100);
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/CYEBC/12/

Note: I'm not sure if this is the desired behavior, but it's what happens when your code is called properly.

Comment: Oh wow. I thought you had to use a string for the first parameter. So now I'm not sure which answer to accept - both seem to do the trick!

Comment: Both answers are correct - I'm accepting this one because it's the simpler of the two (barely). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function `galleryScroll()` isn't defined in the correct scope to be evaluated in `setTimeout()`. If you want it running in a loop, call it in `setInterval()` after the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('#box').offset().left;
    var y = $('#box').offset().top;
    galleryScroll();

    function galleryScroll() {
        x = x + 1;
        y = y + 1;
        $('#box').offset({
            left: x,
            top: y
        });
    }
    // Call in setInterval() outside the function definition.
    // Note also, I've changed the eval string 'gallerySroll()' to the function reference galleryScroll
    setInterval(galleryScroll, 100);
});​
```

[Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CYEBC/10/)

Comment: It isn't that `galleryScroll` isn't defined at the time it's called by `setTimeout`, but rather that it's not defined in the proper scope for a string that is eval'd in the global scope.